# HTML symbols using shell

Tags: linux, html

I have below code in unix where i need to convert COMPLETED pattern to [image]

```
sed 's/COMPLETED/<b><span style="color:green; font-weight:900;">\&#10145;<\/span><\/b>/' T.html > output.html
```

The above code is not printing the expected output. Can anyone help on this?

it is having below output

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output and, what output you get? Please post text as text with code formatting.

Comment: I have mentioned the image in the 1st line as what is the expected output. And in the below i have mentioned what is the output which i get while implementing the sed command in image @muru

Comment: Your code is operating on *text*. The output is text, the input is text. Show us the ***text***.

Comment: @muru, technically, the output is text in a particular font weight and colour though it's true the problem here seems to be what text is being used rather than colour and weight.

Answer (score 0):

The ⇨ character (U+21E8, RIGHTWARDS WHITE ARROW, `&#8680;`) looks closer to what you want.

(U+1F8A7, RIGHTWARDS LEFT-SHADED WHITE ARROW, `&#129191;`) even closer.

Your `&#10145;` is the *U+27A1 BLACK RIGHTWARDS ARROW* character.

So:

```
sed 's|COMPLETED|<b><span style="color:green; font-weight:900;">\&#129191;</span></b>|' T.html > output.html
```

Here also using `|` instead of `/` as the separator since `/` occurs in the replacement string.

Note that  was added to Unicode in 7.0 in 2014 while ⇨has been there since as far back as 1.1 in 1993. So ⇨ may be more portable.

Some useful commands:

```
$ printf '&#%d;\n' "''"
&#129191;
$ printf '&#x%x;\n' "''"
&#x1f8a7;
$ printf 'U+%04X\n' "''"
U+1F8A7
```

```
$ printf '' | uconv -x hex/xml
&#x1F8A7;
$ printf '' | uconv -x hex/xml10                                                                                                                                               
&#129191;
$ printf '' | uconv -x name     
\N{RIGHTWARDS LEFT-SHADED WHITE ARROW}
```

```
$ unicode ''               
U+1F8A7 RIGHTWARDS LEFT-SHADED WHITE ARROW
UTF-8: f0 9f a2 a7 UTF-16BE: d83edca7 Decimal: &#129191; Octal: \0374247

Category: So (Symbol, Other); East Asian width: N (neutral)
Unicode block: 1F800..1F8FF; Supplemental Arrows-C
Bidi: ON (Other Neutrals)
```

(From `unicode` Debian package).

Comment: But while executing the code and sending the output of html file in the body of email i am getting ? in a box as an output for the completed pattern.

Comment: Ca anyone help? the   is not coming. Instead it is having formating issue while sending over the email. it is coming as ? in box

Comment: @DeepMukherjee, what software on what system (and what versions thereof) are you using to view your emails?

Comment: i am using outlook to view the email

Comment: and also below code is used to send the email          export MAILTO="<mailid>"
export CONTENT="output.html"
export SUBJECT="Status"
(
echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: text/html charset=UTF-8"
echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
cat $CONTENT
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO

Comment: @DeepMukherjee. Try with a proper mail reader. Or ask on a Microsoft forum.

Comment: My code :- sed  's/WAITING/<span style="color:green; font-weight:900;font-size:17px">\&#x1F51C;<\/span>/g' is actually working. It will send ✓ in email which actually we are getting. But the problem is with the code :- sed 's|COMPLETED|<b><span style="color:green; font-weight:900;">\&#129191;</span></b>|' T.html > output.html the   is not gtetting. I dont know why

Comment: It would seem that the font used by your current email reader does not have the   symbol, and so it shows the Unicode "unknown/undisplayable character" symbol (`?` in a box) instead. Alternatively, the mail server might include a spam/malware filter that uses an old version of Unicode: it might not recognize the arrow character and could replace it with the error symbol.